# Howto flag Wordpress (and other blog/cms) support questions

Tags: discussion, flags, site-recommendation

I see a lot of WordPress questions. Most of them about plugin development. But there are a lot of support/maintenance-questions as well.
Instead of writing an answer like: check Super User or Server Fault, is there any way I can flag the question?

Comment: There is a [WordPress.SE] Stack Exchange site for WP developers and administrators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "other" flag option to send a custom message.

However please bear in mind the following:

1. We don't migrate poor quality questions. If it's not a brilliant question we're unlikely to migrate it. In this case just flag/vote as "unclear what you are asking" or simply "off topic -> other".
2. We can't migrate questions that are older than 60 days.
3. There's a good chance that the question will already have been asked on the target site, so in this case migration would cause **more** work for their moderators.